# how to find that my written content is unique - in terms of google and user?

Tags: seo, google, content, duplicate-content

how to find that my written content is unique - in terms of google and user?

I also want to know whether updating the content or user commenting on that article helps in seo?

Answer (score 2):

[Copyscape](http://www.copyscape.com/) can help find content that has also been published on other websites. [Google alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts) can tell you when Google  finds content you specify on another website.

Updating the content won't have a direct effect on SEO as changing content is not a ranking factor. But if you improve the content it may become relevant for search phrases and it may encourage other webmasters to link to it. Of course, this is assuming the content is significantly improved in the update.

Comment: Thanks. However, can you tell me how to use google alerts?

Comment: [Here's a bunch of sites that explain how](http://www.google.com/webhp?q=how+to+use+google+alerts+to+find+duplicate+content#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&site=webhp&source=hp&q=how+to+use+google+alerts+to+find+duplicate+content&pbx=1&oq=how+to+use+google+alerts+to+find+duplicate+content&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=0l0l0l1489l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=d3b0899f6de92b8&biw=1278&bih=851)